# Android Manifest - device compatability list, missing Galaxy S2

Tags: android, manifest, compatibility, device, galaxy

I've been preparing to publish my app but i've been running into a device compatibility issue where i've only been recieveing around 215 devices or less compatible. The most noticable one for me is the Samsung Galaxy S2, now i've tested thoroughly on this device and it works perfectly. I was wondering if anyone here could see anything in my manifest that might be missing/causing a conflict.

Note: Using Unity android and OpenFeint with this project.

These are the features that the market only display too apparently:

> Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE Required device features
>   android.hardware.touchscreen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.openfeint.api" android:versionName="1.4.1" android:versionCode="6">
  <supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.IntroFlow"
                  android:label="IntroFlow"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

        <activity android:name="com.openfeint.api.ui.Dashboard"
                  android:label="Dashboard"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

        <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.Settings"
                  android:label="Settings"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

        <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.NativeBrowser"
          android:label="NativeBrowser"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is not correct - you cant use required="false" in uses-permission, it has to be in uses-feauture. Like this for phone state:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

More about this in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Answer (score 0):

READ_PHONE_STATE will cause Android Market filtering on some tablets, try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" required="false">
```